# find returns two line-item entries for the same file

Tags: find

The command:

```
find . ! -name '*153902*.json' -exec ls -nls {} + | sort -k 10
```

returns:

```
12 -rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000  8359 May  6 15:11 ./Flights20180506-151026_KSEA_300.json
12 -rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000  8359 May  6 15:11 Flights20180506-151026_KSEA_300.json
44 -rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000 40999 May  6 15:39 Flights20180506-153902_KATL_0.json
```

This snippet of the response shows that the first two line-items appear to represent the same file: the difference is a './' prepended to the filename.  What does this first line-item represent and why does the third line item not have a ./ ?

```
myname@Metropolitan:~/FlightAwareXML3/Thanksgiving18$ find . ! -name '*153902*.json' -exec ls -nlst {} \; | grep 153902_KATL_0
44 -rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000 40999 May  6 15:39 Flights20180506-153902_KATL_0.json
```

## QUESTIONS

1. What is the unique keywords to Google to learn more about ./ syntax?
2. Is it possible (if yes how) to eliminate first-line-item response with the ./

Answer (score 6):

Here's the process:

```
find . ! -name '*153902*.json'
```

will return:

```
.
./Flights20180506-151026_KSEA_300.json
```

then the `exec` executes:

```
ls -nls . ./Flights20180506-151026_KSEA_300.json
```

which give you the content of `.`:

```
12 -rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000  8359 May  6 15:11 Flights20180506-151026_KSEA_300.json
44 -rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000 40999 May  6 15:39 Flights20180506-153902_KATL_0.json
```

and `./Flights20180506-151026_KSEA_300.json` itself.

---

The `./` you see in the output, is the result of concatenate the path `.` with the filename which matches your condition. The behavior is described in [POSIX find document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47_03):

> Each path operand shall be evaluated unaltered as it was provided,
>   including all trailing  characters; all pathnames for other
>   files encountered in the hierarchy shall consist of the concatenation
>   of the current path operand, a  if the current path operand did
>   not end in one, and the filename relative to the path operand

Answer (score 0):

When looking for regular files with `find`, make sure you use `-type f`:

```
find . -type f ! -name '*153902*.json'
```

This way, you avoid matching directory names, in particular `.` in this case.